# How to set cancel url paypal express checkout?

Tags: php, paypal

How to set cancel url paypal express checkout ?

For me, when buyer cancel purchase on paypal site. paypal will redirect my buyer to `https://www.example.com/index.php?token=EC-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

How to set for redirect to other page ?

I tried to use this code

```
$PayPalCancelURL = 'https://www.example.com/other_page.php';
```

and

```
'&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL).
```

But still redirect to `https://www.example.com/index.php?token=EC-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

How can i do that ?

Comment: Refer to the paypal docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with the following example:

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html